# Как изменить URL фона?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Нужно изменить URL фона при нажатии на ссылку, но не получается это сделать.
Где я допускаю ошибку?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next_slayd").click(function() {
        var background = $(".width_zone").css('background', 'url(../img/For_grey_block_imak.png')
        return false;   
    });
});
```

Comment: `url(../img/For_grey_block_imak.png` - возможная опечатка, скобки не хватает закрывающей

Comment: @ThisMan опечатка тут есть очень даже точно. Однако некоторые браузеры могут исправить её сами. Так что если у автора новая версия Chrome, то проблема может быть в чём-то ещё.

Comment: Не считаю это поводом не занятся ее устранением в первую очередь

Comment: @ThisMan исправить её надо - кто бы спорил. Я же говорю про то, что автору стоит добавить в вопрос соответствующий HTML-код для того, чтобы можно было оценить ситуацию в целом.

Comment: Зачем `var background = ...`, если нужно просто заменить картинку при клике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое - исправьте опечатку

Второе - проверьте, есть ли элемент с классом, на который вы вещаете обработчик, элемент с классом, которому пытаетесь поменять фон.

Третье - пишите так

```
$(el).css({ prop: value })
```

Так можно и несколько св-в сразу изменять

Answer (score 0):

У вас ни то, что не закрыта скобка, но и `;` не стоит перед `return false;`.

Ниже написал 2 варианта решения данной задачи.

1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next_slayd").click(function() {
        $(".width_zone").css({'background':'url("../img/For_grey_block_imak.png")'});
        return false;   
    });
});
```

2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".next_slayd").click(function() {
        $(".width_zone").attr('style','background:url("../img/For_grey_block_imak.png")');
        return false;   
    });
});
```

**P.S** Эти варианты будут работать, только если элемент с классом `.next_slayd` не создаётся динамически.

Comment: Чем не угодил его вариант вызова `css`? Там же надо всего одну круглую скобку добавить.

Comment: Можно и его вариант вызова подставить, тоже будет работать. Мне просто привычнее писать этот вариант.